# C99 structs shared member access

Tags: struct, c99

I'm wondering if there any situation where this will fail due to memory alignment or any other consideration that I have not taken into account.

I want to know if in every case a pointer to a struct can be cast safely to its first member and if there is any C99 way of having generic access for different structs that share some member.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
  uint8_t m1;
  uint8_t m2;
  uint8_t m3;
  uint8_t m4;
  uint8_t m5;
} S1;

typedef struct {
  uint8_t m1;
  double  m2;
  float   m3;
} S2;

typedef struct {
  uint8_t m1;
  S1      m2;
  S2      m3;
} S3;

int main(void) {

  S1 var1 = {.m1 = 12};
  S2 var2 = {.m1 = 13};
  S3 var3 = {.m1 = 14};

  uint8_t * p;

  p = (uint8_t*) &var1;
  printf("var1 %d\n", *p);

  p = (uint8_t*) &var2;
  printf("var2 %d\n", *p);

  p = (uint8_t*) &var3;
  printf("var3 %d\n", *p);

  return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: no it cannot it depends on OS (for your first question).

Comment: Your structures will be optimized by the compiler, ranging from biggest to smallest, and their size will likely match a power of two. What you are trying to do is very dangerous and may work, but certainly not safely.